# how do i punctuate php curl statements

Tags: php, php-curl

i am not profficeint in php when i encounter the term curl.

The below code apparently needs a correction.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, {
"ShortCode": 600981,
"ResponseType": "Completed",
"ConfirmationURL": "https://mydomainx.com/confirmation",
"ValidationURL": "https://mydomainx.com/validation",
});
```

It gives an error

syntax error. unexpected '{' on the very first line.
I will try any help offered.

Comment: As you want an array, replace the `{}` with `[]`.

Comment: and `:` with `=>`, recheck basic array syntax docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass data as an array

```
$data = json_encode(array(
    "ShortCode" => "600981",
    "ResponseType" => "Completed",
    "ConfirmationURL" => "https://mydomainx.com/confirmation",
    "ValidationURL" => "https://mydomainx.com/validation",
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

Comment: its working! I do not understand it but only copy paste and error is resolved!

Comment: we only pass the array key => value, then encode it. its just like normal key value of javascript object